# Querying multiple collections of firestore using array-contains-any

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying query a number of documents in different collections with `array-contains-any`, by using `Promise.all()` to get all the documents at once.

I've checked whether the path is correct, whether the documents exist, whether the `key` exists in the document and everything is ok.

The `querySnapshots` and `snapshots` have no data retrieved. At some point of the log says: **"_size":0,"_materializedDocs":null**.

```
  let promises = []
  depIds.forEach(id => {
    const prodIds = groupedProducts[id].reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val.prodId], []);
    console.log("All prodIds: ", prodIds, "; also id is: ", id);
    promise = admin.firestore()
      .collection('Products')
      .doc('Departments')
      .collection(id)
      .where('key', 'array-contains-any', prodIds)
      .get();
    promises.push(promise)

  })

  const querySnapshots = await Promise.all(promises);
  const snapshots = querySnapshots.map(doc => {
    console.log("docs: ", JSON.stringify(doc))
    return doc;
  });
```

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to query as above?
2. How to get the actual data after the `Promise.all()` command?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `key` field in your document is a string, you should be using the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

The [`array-contains-any` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) checks if any of the values you have given are in the **array** of the named field. As `key` is a string, this operator will always return no results.

To get all documents where `key` matches a given ID, while also ensuring that you can fetch more than 10 documents at a time, you can use:

```
/** splits array `arr` into chunks of max size `n` */
function chunkArr(arr, n) {
  if (n <= 0) throw new Error("n must be greater than 0");
  return Array
    .from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length/n)})
    .map((_, i) => arr.slice(n*i, n*(i+1)))
}

/** Fetch all given product IDs (if they exist) for the given department */
fetchDepartmentProducts(depId, prodIdList) {
  const prodIdListInBatches = chunkArr(prodIdList, 10);
  const departmentCollectionRef = admin.firestore()
    .collection('Products')
    .doc('Departments')
    .collection(depId);
  
  const promises = prodIdListInBatches.map((prodIdListBatch) => {
    return departmentCollectionRef
      .where('key', 'in', prodIdListBatch)
      .get();
  });
  
  return Promise.all(promises) // waits for all get requests
    .then((allQuerySnapshots) => {
      // flatten the found documents of the query snapshots into one array
      const allDocSnapshots = [];
      allQuerySnapshots.forEach((querySnapshot) =>
        allFoundDocSnapshots.push(...querySnapshot.docs)
      );
      return allDocSnapshots;
    });
}
```

Working this into your code, gives:

```
const promises = depIds.map((id) => {
  const prodIds = groupedProducts[id].map((product) => product.prodId);
  return fetchDepartmentProducts(id, prodIds);
}

const productsByDepartment = await Promise.all(promises);

productsByDepartment.forEach((docsInDeparment, i) => {
  console.log(`Found ${docsInDeparment.length} products in department #${depId[i]}.`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Split the array into chunks of 10 made all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to query as above

Yes, it is totally possible since the `get()` method returns a Promise that will be resolved with the results of the Query (i.e. a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot))

> How to get the actual data after the Promise.all() command?

`await Promise.all(promises);` returns a single Promise that "resolves to an array of the results of the input promises" (MDN [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)), i.e. in your case to an Array of `QuerySnapshot`s.

So to read the results you need to loop on the Array and for each element loop on the `QuerySnapshot`. For example as follows:

```
  const promises = [];
  depIds.forEach((id) => {
    const prodIds = groupedProducts[id].reduce(
      (acc, val) => [...acc, val.prodId],
      []
    );
    console.log('All prodIds: ', prodIds, '; also id is: ', id);
    promise = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('Products')
      .doc('Departments')
      .collection(id)
      .where('key', 'array-contains-any', prodIds)
      .get();
    promises.push(promise);
  });

  const querySnapshots = await Promise.all(promises);

  const docs = [];
  
  querySnapshots.forEach(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          docs.push(doc.data());
      });
  });
```

---

I've used `forEach` to loop over the Array of `QuerySnapshot`s but you may adapt it with any other way of looping over/mapping an Array

Comment: As [@samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67313319/4300670) pointed out, my mistake was to search an array, when in fact I should be searching in a field in the document.

Answer (score 0):

To query, the index must first exist. Check your Firebase console or your app console to make sure there are no `index not created` warnings.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Firestore also has an inherent spam limit before it blocks requests, make sure that you batch your methods to be no more than 50 concurrent pending.

Comment: Everything was checked beforehand. Thank you for your help!